# Replicate eksctl cluster creation with OIDC

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cdk, eksctl

I'd like to recreate this functionality in CDK

```
eksctl create cluster \
    --name <<cluster-name>> \
    --region <<region>> \
    --with-oidc \
    --nodes=3
```

My cdk cluster creation looks like this (in python)

```py
cluster = eks.Cluster(
            self, "my-cluster",
            cluster_name="my-cluster",
            version=eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_21,
        )
```

When I try to add an iamserviceaccount to the cluster I get this error

```
Error: unable to create iamserviceaccount(s) without IAM OIDC provider enabled
```

I then have to add OIDC via eksctl, but I'd like to be able to do it in CDK, I couldn't find anything in the documentation to help me do this, was wondering if anyone had some advice?

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript you can do something like this:

```
new OpenIdConnectProvider(this, 'OidcProvider', {
    url: this.cluster.clusterOpenIdConnectIssuerUrl
});
```

and then you should be able to deal with the IAM roles. Here, the `OpenIdConnectProvider` is the one from the [`aws-eks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-eks.OpenIdConnectProvider.html) package, not the `aws-iam` package.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up specifying an alb_controller in the cluster definition, and this automatically created the oidc provider in IAM.

```py
cluster = eks.Cluster(
    self, "my-cluster",
    cluster_name="my-cluster",
    version=eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_21,
    alb_controller={
        "version": eks.AlbControllerVersion.V2_3_1,
    }
)
```